# Concat ReactElements to render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an `If` component in React that is very straightforward:

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react');

module.exports = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        if (this.props.condition) {
            return this.props.children;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

I can call it like:

```
<If condition={someLogic}>
    <div>Hi there</div>
</If>
```

The problem is if I have multiple tags inside the `If` component:

```
<If condition={someLogic}>
    <div>Container 1</div>
    <div>Container 2</div>
</If>
```

This gives me an error:

> Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: exports.render(): A valid
>   ReactComponent must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an
>   array or some other invalid object.

Here `this.props.condition` is an array of `ReactElement`.

**Question:** How do I concat an array of `ReactElement` and return just one?

*Note:* I realize that I can put both of these `divs` inside one wrapper, but for the sake of this example (and my actual problem), let's say that you cannot do that, and that you'd have to return multiple tags

Comment: Did you try somethings like `return <div>{this.props.children}</div>` ?

Comment: Please read my `Note`. I said I realize that I can wrap my `children`, but for the sake of argument, let's say that I can't

Comment: React expects each component to return only one root element https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.createclass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React does not support returning multiple components from render. Render method must return one element - you can see issues https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2127 and https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2191

Solution is wrap props.children by some element, for example

```
var If = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    if (this.props.condition) {
      return <div>{this.props.children}</div>;
    }
    return false;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

An other solution to solve what you want to do (not what you are asking for) is to use a functional `if`:

```
function test (condition, result, alternative) {
  if (condition) {
    return result;
  } else {
    return alternative;
  }
}


<div>
  {test(a === b, <b>Equal</b>)}
</div>
```

This is equivalent to the ternary operator `{a === b ? <b>Equal</b> : null}`.